# Dynamically calling a method name on an object

Tags: javascript

While it's a terrible idea to call a method that is entered by the user, but in language like Ruby you can call method() on an Object using a.method(), but you can also use send(method_name, other_object), for example:

```
$ ruby -e "p '1234abc'.send(:to_i)"
1234

ruby -e "puts '1234ab'.method(:to_i).call"
1234
```

Another Example:

```
ruby -e "n1, n2 = 5, 6 ; puts %i(+ - * / fdiv).map { |x| %[#{n1} #{x} #{n2} = #{n1.send(x, n2)}] }"
5 + 6 = 11
5 - 6 = -1
5 * 6 = 30
5 / 6 = 0
5 fdiv 6 = 0.8333333333333334
```

Another example:

```
$ ruby -e "puts ; n = ->n { print %(Enter #{n}: ) ; STDIN.gets.strip } ; num1 = n.('first value') ; num2 = n.('second value') ; meth = n.('method name') ; puts num1.to_i.send(meth, num2.to_i)"

Enter first value: 5
Enter second value: 10
Enter method name: *
50

$ ruby -e "puts ; n = ->n { print %(Enter #{n}: ) ; STDIN.gets.strip } ; num1 = n.('first value') ; num2 = n.('second value') ; meth = n.('method name') ; puts num1.to_i.send(meth, num2.to_i)"

Enter first value: 50 
Enter second value: 20  
Enter method name: fdiv
2.5
```

Can I do the same with JS?

For example:

```
var foo = '+'
1.call(foo, 2)    # => 3
8.call('*', 5)    # => 40
'Hello World'.call(split, ' ')    # => ["Hello", "World"]
```

Comment: maybe something like [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) ?

Comment: I have a variable `foo = '+'` ; and I want to call it on 1 with 2, say `1.call(foo, 2)`, instead of 1 + 2...

Comment: You can - and as you realise you probably shouldn't:  let functionName = "printMethod";

eval(functionName + '("from eval call")');

function printMethod(from){
  console.log("Hello World " + from);
}

Comment: `+` is not a method, it is an operator.

Comment: Yes, JS by nature is a dynamic language.  So `object["someMethod"](params)` would call a method called `someMethod` on object.  But be aware `this` context is not automatically bound when doing this, that's what call and bind are used for.  So you might want `object["someMethod"].call(object, params)`

Comment: You could define methods for each operation (eg: `var operations = { '+': (n1, n2) => (n1 + n2) }`) and then call the appropriate function using the user input (eg: `operations[x](n1, n2)`)

Comment: Hi @keith, `js> 1['+'](54)  
typein:9:3 TypeError: 1['+'] is not a function
Stack:
  @typein:9:3
` Same with `.call(param)`, Using SpiderMonkey `JavaScript-C73.0`

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong, but so far https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable doesn't actually solve my question...

Comment: It doesn't because that relates to accessing properties of an object using a **string**. In **JavaScript**, `+` is an operator not a function, there is no equivalent for the `ruby` approach, look at my previous comment for an alternative.

Comment: Oh I see, can't really do anything like that...